# Some links do not appear bold after css styling to make the letters bold

Tags: html, css, styling

I have this css:

```
.content .chapter_text li a 
{
    color: #7e9940;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And on the same page, it has places where it works, and also places where it doesn't work.

Take a look here: http://www.comehike.com - on the bottom of the page, the links appear in bold text.  In the middle of the page, the links appear in non-bold text.

But they are styled the same - as far as I can tell.  Any idea why the links in the middle of the home page do not appear bold?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because those link in the center are not in a `li`. You could modify your CSS to the following to get the wanted result:

```
.content .chapter_text a 
{
    color: #7e9940;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

They are not contained in a `li` element so the style does not apply. You have to move them into a li or make it like;

```
.content .chapter_text li a, .content .chapter_text p a {    
    color: #7e9940;    text-decoration: none;    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The links in the middle of the page are not children of an li element, which is what your selector targets.